# Question on double-asymmetric encryption and split knowledge

Tags: rsa, public-key, perfect-secrecy, multiple-encryption, distributed-decryption

Moin moin,

- Let‘s assume there are two keypairs `(d1,e1)` and `(d2,e2)`, where `d1` and `d2` are unrelated private keys and `e1` and `e2` the corresponding public keys.
- Imagine Alice knowing **neither `d1` nor `d2`** and Bob only `d1`, **not `d2`**.
- Alice has a ciphertext `c` resulting from encrypting a message `m` with `e1` using RSA. She cannot decrypt it because she doesn‘t know `d1`.
- Alice encrypts `c` again with `e2` using an asymmetric cipher (remains to be chosen) and sends it to Bob.
- Bob can‘t decrypt it since he doesn‘t have `d2`.
- Can he then use some kind of algorithm and `d1` to produce something which he can send to me that can be decrypted with `d1` and `d2` resulting in the original message?

What I want is, that Alice and Bob cannot read the message, only the combined knowledge of both secret keys would allow them to decipher it.

**Pseudocode:**

`m` is the message

```
c := RSAEncrypt(m, using: e1)
```

Alice does:

```
c2 := AsymEncrypt(c, using: e2)
```

Bob does:

```
c3 := RSADecryptAlgo(c2, using: d1)
```

I want to:

```
m = SomeDecryptionAlgo(c3, using: d2)
```

*Is this scenario (though quite strange) even possible? If so, does anyone know a googleable term or an algorithm/s which would fit my case?*

Edit: The keypairs do not share the same modulus

Comment: Hi. What did you mean with "unrelated private keys", did that include the same modulus?

Comment: To clarify, the moduli are different

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is, that Alice and Bob cannot read the message, only their
> combined knowledge would allow them to decipher it.

"Committing with partial knowledge of group order" scenario was presented at the [CECC 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20110813080702/http://cecc.amu.edu.pl/index.php?doc=program).

A scheme was designed such that order of an RSA-like multiplicative group is split into two parts shared by two parties such that both must participate to decrypt. Technically, modulus is a product of four primes, spit into two pairs for each party.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing but to me it feels very related to a [three-pass protocol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-pass_protocol). Specifically, we require a "commutative" (order-independent) encryption scheme, where (for all messages),
$$c = Enc(k_1, Enc(k_2, m)) = Enc(k_2, Enc(k_1, m)).$$

In this case, the ciphertext $c$ can be decrypted with $k_1$ and $k_2$ in either order to re-obtain $m$.

I believe this is only possible with RSA if both keys use the same modulus. It can also be done with ElGamal ([reference](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6449730)) and maybe other schemes too. In any case, it's probably only possible if both keys/encryption steps use the same algorithm & public parameters.